# Why does pg gem automatically cast 'A' to 0 for an integer type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a column defined as integer in Postgresql and wrote a test to assign the character 'A' and expected a database error to be thrown.

However, it appears that pg automatically maps characters to '0'.

I can't think of any good reason for this functionality and am inclined to think that it is a bad idea to over-ride the implicit constraint that an integer should in fact be an integer.

Am I missing some big picture here?

Updating:

Thanks for the quick response (mu_is_too_short). You are right in that 'A'.to_i returns 0 and 0 is a valid value so a CHECK would not help. I will have numeric validation in the model so I suppose this doesn't really matter. It's just that I was trying to check that the database column was correctly configured as integer. I suppose Rspec tests are really targeted at the layers above the database.

Updating Again...

I created the following class:

```
class Notaninteger

  def initialize(par)
    @par = par
  end

  def to_i
    @par
  end

end
```

I thought this might counter AR's attempts to call to_i. However, this doesn't seem to work. Drat, foiled again!

Updating for the last time...

The following works:

```
class Notaninteger

  def to_i
    self
  end

end
```

I suspect AR may call to_i several times and the above always returns a Notaninteger object.

```
2.1.4 :002 > range.start_of_range = 'A'
=> "A" 
2.1.4 :003 > range.save!
(0.4ms)  BEGIN SQL (11.6ms)  INSERT INTO "coderanges" ("comment", "created_at", "end_of_range", "groupname", "name", "protection", "start_of_range", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["comment", nil], ["created_at", Wed, 11 Mar 2015 21:46:52 UTC +00:00], ["end_of_range", nil], ["groupname", nil], ["name", nil], ["protection", nil], ["start_of_range", 0], ["updated_at", Wed, 11 Mar 2015 21:46:52 UTC +00:00]]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the pg gem doing the cast, that's ActiveRecord calling `to_i` on the string when you do the `range.start_of_range = 'A'` assignment. AR is calling `to_i` because, presumably, the column is an integer.

If zero isn't a valid value for `start_of_range` then you should add a validation to check it (and, if you're properly paranoid like me, add a CHECK constraint inside the database to match your validation).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You are right in that 'A'.to_i returns 0.